# integrating this infinite gaussian integral

Tags: integration, special-functions

How does one integrate

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x e^{-\lambda ( x-a )^2 }dx $
where $\lambda$ is a positive constant.

My integral tables are not returning anything useable. The best it return is non-definite gaussian integrals. Useless!

Help please

Comment: Are you sure this is the right integral? Cause yours does not seem to converge at the moment.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is constant, take $e^{-\lambda}$ out of the integral.

Comment: Check the integrand, please. Could it be $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x e^{-\lambda \left ( x-a \right )^{2}}dx$ instead ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici sorry careless typo

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x e^{-\lambda(x-a)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x+a) e^{-\lambda x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\frac{a}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=a\sqrt{\frac\pi\lambda}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto x+a$
$(2)$: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xe^{-\lambda x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=0\because$ odd integrand, then substitute $x\mapsto\frac x{\sqrt\lambda}$
$(3)$: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt\pi$

Answer (score 0):

If the integral follows the comments above here is a hint.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda(x-a)^2}dx
$$
let $\lambda(x-a)^2 = \frac{z^2}{2}\to z=\sqrt{2\lambda}(x-a)$ 
we get
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\lambda}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2\lambda}}+a\right)\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz
$$

Comment: I was just typing the same when your answer came. You are too fast for the old man ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Just by curiosity, why not just $\lambda(x-a)^2 = {z^2}$ ?

Comment: Hey @ClaudeLeibovici it is a force of habit since $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} = N(0,1)$$ ;).

Comment: I was sure that this was the "contamination" !!! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If the integral is the one you wrote, then of course no table gives you any hint: that integral does not converge. Indeed:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xe^{-\lambda}(x-a)^2\ \text{d}x = e^{-\lambda}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x^3 + a^2 x - 2ax^2)\ \text{d}x$$

And you easily can integrate it, but it will diverge.

**So I think you wrote wrong, and the real integral is**

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x e^{-\lambda(x-a)^2}\ \text{d}x$$

At this point you can use

$$\sqrt{\lambda}(x-a) = y ~~~~~~~ \text{d}y = \sqrt{\lambda}\ \text{d}x ~~~~~~~ x = \frac{y}{\sqrt{\lambda}}+a$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: Can I confirm that there is an even and odd integrand? It seem so unless I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }dxx\exp [-\lambda (x-a)^{2}]=\int_{-\infty
}^{+\infty }dx(x+a)\exp [-\lambda x^{2}]=a\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }dx\exp
[-\lambda x^{2}]
\end{equation*}